# Can't extract user facebook email address from OAuth iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, email, sdk, oauth

Can you help with some stuck here, let's look on code first,
here i ask for permissions

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    [params setObject:facebook._appId forKey:@"client_id"];
    [params setObject:@"token" forKey:@"response_type"];
    [params setObject:[NSString stringWithCString:"email,user_about_me,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:@"scope"];
    [facebook dialog:@"oauth" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
    [params release];
```

Here use @"me" for graph API

```
- (void)fbDidLogin 
{
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];

}
```

But all what i get is

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;
    NSLog(@"FB result %@", result);
}
```

FB result (
    "Justfortest Workingin",
    100002369945695
)

But how to get email address ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer was that fb not return email and other data with

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

only id and name.

I need to simply put in

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
```

another call for user data.

Finally needed method looks like this:

```
    - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
    {
        NSData * dt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=%@",facebook.accessToken]]];
        NSDictionary *response = (NSDictionary*)[[JSONDecoder decoder] objectWithData:dt];
        NSLog(@"fb response %@",response);
        if ([response objectForKey:@"email"]) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[response objectForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"fbEmail"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[response objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"fbId"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:facebook.accessToken forKey:@"fbToken"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:facebook.expirationDate forKey:@"fbExDate"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
    }
```

And i got all user data, thx to all for help, hope this will be helpful for someone.
Also thx to guys from http://midatlanticconsulting.com who help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kYourAppID andDelegate:self];    
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_stream",@"publish_actions", @"email",@"user_about_me",@"offline_access",nil];
[facebook authorize:permissions];
[permissions release];
```

Then you should get everything you need

For the dialog instead of web browser this is what you need:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];
[params setObject:kFBAppId forKey:@"client_id"];
[params setObject:@"publish_stream,email,offline_access" forKey:@"scope"];
// Now popup the login dialog
[facebook dialog:@"oauth" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: I don't want open it in browser, i want to use dialog

Comment: Same result, it gives me my Username and my Id, but still no email

Comment: Have you registered your Application in Facebook and got an FB app ID?

Comment: It's test, i'll change for release )